# Amend script to move Google Sheet tabs into the correct order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 30 near-identical tabs in a Google sheet. It also contains many other tabs.

Now and then I need to make changes to one of the 30, named SUR. When I am satisfied with the change I need to delete 29 tabs, then recreate them by duplicating the SUR tab and storing the name of each new tab in cell A1.

I got ChatGPT to write the script because I have no training in this field and it did a pretty good job. It works.

But I want the new tabs to appear before the SUR tab, in the right order. The SUR tab is somewhere in the middle and its position **might** change, depending on other requirements later.

No matter how I try to explain this to ChatGPT, it seems unable to accomplish it. In various attempts, the code has put the all the new tabs at the beginning, or at the end, or in reverse sequence of the array.

As I mentioned there are other tabs e.g. "Data", "Summary", which should not be affected in any way. The 29 tabs mentioned in the array should appear, in order, directly before the SUR tab, when they have been created.

In fact, if it's easier, they could go directly after the SUR tab instead. Provided the stay in the right order and appear either just before or just after the SUR tab, I'd be happy.

Can anyone help me fix it?

```
function duplicateAndRenameTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SUR');
  var tabNames = ["AGE", "ANA", "CAN", "CAR", "CHI", "CRI", "DEM", "DER", "DIA", "ENT", "GAS", "GEN", "HAE", "HSR", "HEP", "INF", "MH", "MET", "MUS", "NEU", "OPH", "ORA", "PC", "PUB", "REN", "REP", "RES", "STR", "TEC"]; // Add the names you want for new tabs here

  // Find the index of the 'SUR' sheet
  var surTabIndex = ss.getSheets().indexOf(sheet);

  // Delete existing tabs with names from the array
  var existingTabs = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = existingTabs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var sheetName = existingTabs[i].getName();
    if (tabNames.indexOf(sheetName) !== -1) {
      ss.deleteSheet(existingTabs[i]);
    }
  }

  // Duplicate the SUR tab and rename it with names from the array in the correct order
  for (var i = 0; i < tabNames.length; i++) {
    // Duplicate the 'SUR' sheet
    var newSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss);
    
    // Rename the new sheet
    newSheet.setName(tabNames[i]);

    // Populate cell A1 with the name of the tab only if it's in the array
    if (tabNames.indexOf(tabNames[i]) !== -1) {
      newSheet.getRange('A1').setValue(tabNames[i]);
    }

    // Move the new sheet immediately before the 'SUR' tab
    ss.setActiveSheet(newSheet);
    ss.moveActiveSheet(surTabIndex);
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe I know how ChatGPT feels because I need a better explanation of what you want.  I could use a couple of examples.

Comment: OK, I have created and shared a test version here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z8lF5HvCNcIgOBsOIy2GJRqaogZSCYZG4EtTl1-8PhM/edit?usp=sharing  It's got none of the calculations or data of my real file, but it has many of the same tabs. 

If you run the script in the file you'll see it working properly for most steps. It's just at the end it fails to position the new tabs properly.

Comment: By the way, how do you get Stack Overflow to email you when there's a response? I can't seem to figure it out!!

Comment: I’m sorry but I do not follow links to off site resources. Every required to answer the question must be posted in the question.

Comment: Try settings / preferences

Comment: OK, but you asked for an example and as this is a Google Sheet I don't know how else to provide one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about having charts in your SUR sheet.  But this should work.

```
function duplicateTabs() {
  let tabs = ["AGE","ANA","CAN"];
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sur = spread.getSheetByName("SUR");
  tabs.forEach( tab => {
      let sheet = spread.getSheetByName(tab);
      if( sheet ) spread.deleteSheet(sheet);
      let index = sur.getIndex();
      sheet = sur.copyTo(spread);
      sheet.setName(tab);
      sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(tab);
      sheet.activate();
      spread.moveActiveSheet(index);
    }
  )
  sur.activate();
}
```

Reference

- [Spreadsheet.deleteSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet))
- [Sheet.getIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getIndex())
- [Sheet.activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())
- [Spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer))

Comment: Thank you. That comes pretty close, but doesn't do everything I need I'm afraid. If I add a new chart to the SUR tab or amend the formatting of an existing one, this code doesn't update the charts on the other tabs.

Comment: Deleting the tabs and then recreating them based on the amended SUR tab, seems to be required. I'm not too worried about slower performance as I will probably only need to do this once a week or so.

The previous code does most of what I need. It just doesn't put the new tabs in the order I need. I might just have to suck iit up and do that part manually.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that charts would be treated any differently than data or formulas in cells.  This works perfectly as far as I can see. Thank you so much!!